# getting __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'outputCols' when doing the oneHotEncoder

Tags: pyspark, one-hot-encoding

```py
stages = []

for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns:

    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(
        inputCol=categoricalCol, outputCol=categoricalCol + "Index"
    )

    encoder = OneHotEncoder(
        inputCols=[stringIndexer.getOutputCol()],
        outputCols=[categoricalCol + "classVec"],
    )

    stages += [stringIndexer, encoder]

    label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol="Status", outputCol="label")

    stages += [label_stringIdx]

    assemblerInputs = [c + "classVsc" for c in categoricalColumns] + numericColumns

    assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs, outputCol="features")

    stages += [assembler]
```

---

```
> TypeError                                 
> Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-18-7156eaeec61b> in <module>
>       2 for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns:
>       3     stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = categoricalCol, outputCol = categoricalCol + 'Index')
> ----> 4     encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCols=[stringIndexer.getOutputCol()], outputCols=[categoricalCol + "classVec"])
>       5     stages += [stringIndexer, encoder]
>       6 label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol = 'Status', outputCol = 'label')
> 
> /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     102             raise TypeError("Method %s forces keyword arguments." % func.__name__)
>     103         self._input_kwargs = kwargs
> --> 104         return func(self, **kwargs)
>     105     return wrapper
>     106 
> 
> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'outputCols'
```

Comment: what's your version of spark ?

Comment: did you make that script ? `/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py`?

Comment: spark version 2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=onehotencoder#pyspark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder

The param is `outputCol`